# Making sparse checkout out of existing Git repository?

Tags: git, cygwin

I have cloned a GIT repository into `~/myrepo.git`.
Repository contains hundreds of directories.

I would like to create several "projects" that contain only a small subset of the directories available, like so:

```
~/project1/dirA
          /dirB
          /dirC

~/project2/dirD
          /dirE
          /dirF
```

What are the Git commands I need to execute in order to make it work properly?

I understand I need to do some config:
`git config core.sparseCheckout true`

then I need to modify `sparse-checkout` file:

```
echo "/dirA" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "/dirB" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "/dirC" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

What comes next?
`git checkout master`?
`git pull`? 
Are any steps missing?

I am using `cygwin` command line Git, and would like to do a bash script that would automaticaly create this kind of project.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mistaken the way sparse checkout works : you must not clone the remote first because it will download everything from the remote. Instead you must :

1. create a local repo with `git init`,
2. then edit `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file to select the subdirectories
3. add the remote `git remote add origin ...`
4. pull from origin

Note that if you want to create a new git repo with only a subset of directories, the command you are looking for is `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`.

Comment: Note that you can do this using `git clone --no-checkout`, using either the existing clone as `origin` or using the upstream URL as `origin` but using `--reference` to point to the existing clone, to avoid duplicating the pack files locally. Replace `git init` and `git remote add` with `git clone --no-checkout`. This gives you the opportunity to edit `.git/info/sparse-checkout` before you run the `git checkout` step.